# Is that possible to find files reside several level down in awk

Tags: awk

May I know is there a way to find certain synctax of words in awk using one liner command whereby the files I'm finding is on deeper hier.  Wondering if 'find" cmd can apply here but I tried with find it is not working for me, probably my usage is wrong.

My command as below and it works beautiful if I placed the command on the same level where the *.abc reside.

```
awk '/hdl_file/{printf "%s",  $0}/input|output/{printf "%s",  $0}' *.abc | sed s/\.aux// | sed s/,//g | sed s/input// | sed s/output// | sed s/=// | sed s/\"//g | sed s/\.ac// | sed s/hdl_file// | awk '{print $NF $0}' | awk '{$NF="";print $0}'
```

However, I need to apply this command to looks for *.abc file on 2 hierarchy deeper.  Tried command below with find but it gave error.

```
find . -mindepth 2 | awk '/hdl_file/{printf "%s",  $0}/input|output/{printf "%s",  $0}' *.abc | sed s/\.aux// | sed s/,//g | sed s/input// | sed s/output// | sed s/=// | sed s/\"//g | sed s/\.ac// | sed s/hdl_file// | awk '{print $NF $0}' | awk '{$NF="";print $0}'
```

awk: No match.

Pls help.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `awk` command followed by **8** `sed` commands followed by two more `awk` commands in a pipeline is horrendous. All that can be combined into one `awk` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use

```
awk '....' */*/*.abc
```

if the files are exactly 2 subdirectories deep. For arbitrary depth, a recent bash can do

```
shopt -s globstar
awk '....' **/*.abc
```

Your pipeline of awks and seds can be reduced to

```
awk '
    /hdl_file/ || /input|output/ {
        gsub(/[,"]/, "")
        sub(/\.aux|\.ac|input|output|hdl_file|=/, "")
        last = $NF
        $NF = ""
        print last, $0
    }             
' *.abc
```

Comment: Hi glenn jackman, I tried to use the */*.abc method (in my actual case is */file1.aux) and it do works to find a single cell. However when I tried t olooks for bunch of cells with my command awk '/input|output/{printf "%s", $0} /hdl_file/{printf "%s", $0}' */*.aux | sed -e 's/\.aux//' -e 's/,//g' -e 's/input//' -e 's/output//' -e 's/=//' -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/\.ac//' -e 's/hdl_file//' | awk '{print $NF $0}' | awk '{$NF="";print $0}’ it do not works properly as it seem like to have the line feed (or carriage return prblm). Wondering what should I do to get rid of this?

Comment: If my cmd like this: awk '/input|output/{printf "%s", $0} /hdl_file/{printf "%s", $0}' */file1.aux | sed -e 's/\.aux//' -e 's/,//g' -e 's/input//' -e 's/output//' -e 's/=//' -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/\.ac//' -e 's/hdl_file//' | awk '{print $NF $0}' | awk '{$NF="";print $0}’ ----- it will output correctly like file1  ck d vcc o

Comment: But if my cmd with asterick, awk '/input|output/{printf "%s", $0} /hdl_file/{printf "%s", $0}' */*.aux | sed -e 's/\.aux//' -e 's/,//g' -e 's/input//' -e 's/output//' -e 's/=//' -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/\.ac//' -e 's/hdl_file//' | awk '{print $NF $0}' | awk '{$NF="";print $0}’ ---- something really goes wrong as it output input ck d den si ssb vccoutput o.ac hdl_file = file1input ck d den si ssb vccoutput o.ac hdl_file = file2input ck d den si ssb vccoutput o.ac hdl_file = file3input ck d den si ssb vccoutput o.ac hdl_file = file40input ck d den si ssb vccoutput o.ac hdl_file =

Comment: @Grace, I can't make out your code. In comments, put code inside backticks for better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's your intention, but `-mindepth` will make `find` search in directories that are *more* than 2 levels down. If you want files that are *at most* 2 levels down, you need to use `-maxdepth`.

If you want to use the output of one command (in this case `find`) as arguments for another command (`awk`), you can use `xargs`, for example:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 | xargs awk '[your awk script goes here]'
```

Or, you could use `-exec` to read the files, if you don't care about their names:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -exec cat '{}' \; | awk '[your awk script goes here]'
# Or possibly:
find . -maxdepth 2 | xargs cat | awk '[your awk script goes here]'
```

Note also, that you can avoid spawning multiple instances of sed and piping them together, here's two ways to do that:

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/something/somethingelse/'
sed -f sed_script  # sed_script is a text file with commands for sed
```

Comment: Hi Staven, thanks for your sample answer and explanation, I need to looks for files ended with *.aux extention, also as you mentioned, yes I want the output from find to perform the awk.  I tried to change my command as below, not sure why it still gave errors.  Cound you help?   Thanks.

Comment: find . -maxdepth 2 | xargs cat | awk '/hdl_file/{printf "%s",  $0}/input|output/{printf "%s",  $0}' *.aux | sed s/\.aux// | sed s/,//g | sed s/input// | sed s/output// | sed s/=// | sed s/\"//g | sed s/\.ac// | sed s/hdl_file// | awk '{print $NF $0}' | awk '{$NF="";print $0}'
awk: cmd. line:2: fatal: cannot open file `file1.aux' for reading (No such file or directory)
cat: .: Is a directory
cat: ./ln: Is a directory
xargs: cat: terminated by signal 13

Comment: @Grace Since `awk` gets only the contents of the files, giving it their names as an argument won't help. You need to add `-name '*.aux'` as an argument to `find`.

Comment: Hi Staven, I tried the find -name "*.aux" before but it flagged err: find . -name "*.aux" | awk '/input|output/{printf "%s",  $0} /hdl_file/{printf "%s",  $0}' *.aux | sed -e 's/\.aux//' -e 's/,//g' -e 's/input//' -e 's/output//' -e 's/=//' -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/\.ac//' -e 's/hdl_file//' | awk '{print $NF $0}' | awk '{$NF="";print $0}'
awk: No match.
I tried the */*.aux finally suggested by glenn jackman and it solved the finding prblm but yet still having line feed prblm while seraching for bunch of cells.  Anyway, I greatly appreciate your help especially for the explaination on the usage.